# What is $\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^k \left(\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{k} \right)$?

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

> Let $a_{n}=(-1)^n \left( \dfrac{1}{2} -\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$ and let $b_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}, \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> Then what is $\lim \sup b_{n}$ and $\lim \inf b_{n}$?

$\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} b_{n} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \left( \frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{n}\right)\\ &= \sum_{n=1}^{ \infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{2} -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{1}{n} \\ &=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{1}{2} -\log 2
\end{align}$

So $\lim \inf b_{n}= \frac{-1}{2}-\log 2$ and $\lim \sup b_{n}= -\log 2$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you committed a small mistake

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} b_{n} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \big( \dfrac{1}{2} -\dfrac{1}{n}\big)\\ 
&= \sum_{n=1}^{ \infty} (-1)^n \dfrac{1}{2} -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \dfrac{1}{n} \\ &=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \dfrac{1}{2}+\log 2
\end{align}

Which implies that 
as

$b_{2n}=\log 2+\frac{1}{2}$

$b_{2n+1}=\log 2-\frac{1}{2}$

$\lim \inf b_{n}=\log 2- \frac{1}{2}$

$\lim \sup b_{n}=\log 2 + \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).